Assigning Numeric year based on July 31th with variable start dates
I'm going to do my best to explain the issue at hand an provide all necessary information.
I have a data set with 10 birds. These 10 birds have observations that could start in 2022, 2023, or even 2024. They could die at any time (which basically means they just stop taking observations).
Okay, so from the very first observation of the bird (which is always between Jan 1st and March 31st), until July 1st, I want a numeric Year value created == 1. Then, from July 31st to the next July 31st, assign a numeric Year value == 2...etc, etc.
Basically, the first 6 ish months of observation (until July 31st), are ALWAYS year 1, even if the bird was started in 2022 vs 2024.
Here is my dataset. It only has 2 birds with one observation per day (normally 12 per day). This is just to make it smaller.
> dput(gps.all.test)
structure(list(birdid = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("2167-56864", 
"2227-85702", "2247-39955", "2247-80346", "2247-80347", "2247-80421", 
"2247-88960", "2257-26581", "2257-26604", "2287-75580"), class = "factor"), 
    timestamp = structure(c(1644777155, 1644845527, 1644935549, 
    1644978749, 1645115594, 1645158773, 1645309994, 1645371215, 
    1645482815, 1645497203, 1645630380, 1645727595, 1645799586, 
    1645900397, 1645975974, 1646062395, 1646155994, 1646253185, 
    1646271177, 1646375593, 1646462003, 1646541200, 1646656398, 
    1646721194, 1646785994, 1646908403, 1646998380, 1647055975, 
    1647142380, 1647218003, 1647344003, 1647390780, 1647527879, 
    1647571079, 1647675464, 1647743851, 1647905915, 1647941864, 
    1648003079, 1648114665, 1648186666, 1648262264, 1648381129, 
    1648467457, 1648539458, 1648625865, 1648766250, 1648852646, 
    1648910494, 1648978887, 1649058089, 1649184119, 1649216485, 
    1649302886, 1649392888, 1649486504, 1649634098, 1649648485, 
    1649770883, 1649842919, 1649936504, 1650033713, 1650112891, 
    1650199318, 1650325313, 1650328899, 1650472890, 1650530513, 
    1650588134, 1650703313, 1650832913, 1650865305, 1650980513, 
    1651102880, 1651128106, 1651192906, 1651336880, 1651398104, 
    1651466514, 1651581708, 1651635714, 1651786914, 1651833679, 
    1651923714, 1652031715, 1652110903, 1652186503, 1652283689, 
    1652330504, 1652416918, 1652532083, 1652658077, 1652690496, 
    1652776896, 1652874120, 1652996507, 1653018104, 1653108096, 
    1653216103, 1653295281, 1653367283, 1653514896, 1653540075, 
    1653615679, 1653738094, 1653802889, 1653874889, 1653968485, 
    1654058478, 1654130486, 1654234876, 1654364485, 1654396896, 
    1654504894, 1654587679, 1654670475, 1654782071, 1654854083, 
    1654972875, 1655023283, 1655088096, 1655242872, 1655271689, 
    1655361679, 1655440872, 1655523673, 1655631669, 1655736094, 
    1655800896, 1655908897, 1656024096, 1656088894, 1656153672, 
    1656236496, 1656304924, 1656430896, 1656474105, 1656578473, 
    1656668499, 1656794503, 1656844957, 1656942098, 1657064496, 
    1657096956, 1657176160, 1657280476, 1657392095, 1657435277, 
    1657503694, 1657665677, 1657698075, 1657827708, 1657888905, 
    1658007742, 1658025689, 1658104886, 1658212896, 1658349694, 
    1658396512, 1658526106, 1658544096, 1658688123, 1658767307, 
    1658799694, 1658950877, 1658997713, 1659094886, 1659184894, 
    1659285686, 1659393678, 1659418880, 1659516094, 1659645701, 
    1659717759, 1659822117, 1659876076, 1659930142, 1660027350, 
    1660099321, 1660185684, 1660272107, 1660408903, 1660452106, 
    1660552918, 1660646480, 1660750905, 1660822903, 1660876905, 
    1661035310, 1661092896, 1661136081, 1661265755, 1661370148, 
    1661445714, 1661532112, 1661582532, 1661679707, 1661802096, 
    1661874106, 1661906496, 1661992891, 1662126094, 1662169307, 
    1662316897, 1662349277, 1662428505, 1662518507, 1662662494, 
    1662756120, 1662770488, 1662939697, 1663026139, 1663083696, 
    1663134106, 1663227719, 1663292483, 1663407678, 1663461714, 
    1663598494, 1663677688, 1663764079, 1663821714, 1663965677, 
    1664044927, 1664084513, 1664196082, 1664318479, 1664394074, 
    1664473279, 1664534478, 1664599299, 1664725277, 1664782876, 
    1664851302, 1664952127, 1665042102, 1665153674, 1665196902, 
    1665315674, 1665402076, 1665499287, 1665610875, 1665675670, 
    1665744073, 1665805323, 1665898906, 1666017702, 1666071732, 
    1666161674, 1666280473, 1666327297, 1666402867, 1666485723, 
    1666575679, 1666658497, 1666762897, 1666903351, 1666957297, 
    1667032897, 1667112093, 1667238097, 1667338886, 1667360497, 
    1667443295, 1667544070, 1667626870, 1667742070, 1667817719, 
    1667936511, 1668022947, 1668094878, 1668210068, 1668228074, 
    1668328863, 1668429668, 1668508871, 1668584469, 1668717676, 
    1668807723, 1668886943, 1668919295, 1669034543, 1669106459, 
    1669236071, 1669268495, 1669351260, 1669488060, 1669574504, 
    1669660889, 1669736492, 1669794089, 1669930874, 1669984890, 
    1670107266, 1670190095, 1670204475, 1670312475, 1670438509, 
    1670488889, 1670571674, 1670658056, 1670802073, 1670877691, 
    1670917260, 1671032475, 1671115284, 1671208863, 1671244876, 
    1671363675, 1671475278, 1671504063, 1671608458, 1671720083, 
    1671777650, 1671882057, 1671961283, 1672058465, 1672130467, 
    1672198883, 1672357265, 1672432889, 1672468875, 1672587660, 
    1672620056, 1672720844, 1672810865, 1672882865, 1673019665, 
    1673116861, 1673206857, 1673268066, 1673358065, 1673444440, 
    1673512865, 1673653243, 1673692848, 1673761289, 1673851265, 
    1673970066, 1674042066, 1674117644, 1674236466, 1674279665, 
    1674430866, 1674438074, 1674567666, 1674675695, 1674776465, 
    1674805237, 1674898833, 1674992434, 1675122039, 1675140033, 
    1675244445, 1675366838, 1675456915, 1675489237, 1675586465, 
    1675662031, 1675777244, 1675892439, 1675932044, 1676058074, 
    1676094030, 1676216434, 1676292050, 1676360444, 1676461274, 
    1676569277, 1676623245, 1676691630, 1676792445, 1676860845, 
    1676990489, 1677098437, 1677184844, 1677220859, 1677354045, 
    1677418828, 1677526836, 1677627646, 1677699660, 1677746460, 
    1677807625, 1677890466, 1678045245, 1678066850, 1678232446, 
    1678318859, 1678401644, 1678473659, 1678542027, 1678628444, 
    1678729342, 1678804992, 1678876833, 1678930852, 1679017255, 
    1679164886, 1679258465, 1679323232, 1679438429, 1679449259, 
    1679611275, 1679683244, 1679748044, 1679870506, 1679892044, 
    1679982053, 1680057695, 1680154845, 1680244859, 1680378022, 
    1680396053, 1680547245, 1680615689, 1680658821, 1680810074, 
    1680900074, 1680921653, 1681062053, 1681087253, 1681224053, 
    1681328419, 1681364419, 1681479631, 1681576824, 1681623645, 
    1681771289, 1681803683, 1681882845, 1682026853, 1682055646, 
    1682142044, 1682271644, 1682347265, 1682415646, 1682548895, 
    1682563235, 1682710818, 1682750439, 1682872838, 1682905235, 
    1683024041, 1683146495, 1683196883, 1683283236, 1683380438, 
    1683488418, 1683506435, 1683650436, 1683747693, 1683816016, 
    1683927618, 1683974411, 1684024836, 1684143665, 1684251635, 
    1684316410, 1684453211, 1684536065, 1684568435, 1684694491, 
    1684734059, 1684838407, 1684942835, 1685022006, 1685083235, 
    1685230828, 1685284822, 1685324408, 1685457635, 1685522407, 
    1685580020, 1685720435, 1685821289, 1685864435, 1685983235, 
    1686055235, 1686123635, 1686231635, 1686325216, 1686411659, 
    1686483606, 1686595206, 1686627612, 1686735608, 1686865235, 
    1686922845, 1687038035, 1687059644, 1687210835, 1687297235, 
    1687326065, 1687434036, 1687520419, 1687606835, 1687693244, 
    1687779636, 1687866065, 1687952435, 1688038844, 1688125283, 
    1688211635, 1688298035, 1688384483, 1642768747, 1642815575, 
    1642952372, 1643006379, 1643081975, 1643171954, 1643247849, 
    1643381076), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    )), JulianDate = c(44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 
    54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 
    69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 
    84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 
    99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 
    111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 
    123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 
    135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 
    147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 
    159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 
    171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 
    183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 
    195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 
    207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 
    219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 
    231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 
    243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 
    255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 
    267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 
    279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290, 
    291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 
    303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 
    315, 316, 317, 318, 319, 320, 321, 322, 323, 324, 325, 326, 
    327, 328, 329, 330, 331, 332, 333, 334, 335, 336, 337, 338, 
    339, 340, 341, 342, 343, 344, 345, 346, 347, 348, 349, 350, 
    351, 352, 353, 354, 355, 356, 357, 358, 359, 360, 361, 362, 
    363, 364, 365, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
    14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 
    29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 
    44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 
    59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 
    74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 
    89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 
    103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 
    115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 
    127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 
    139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 
    151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 
    163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 
    175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 21, 22, 
    23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28), Year = c(2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
    2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
    2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
    2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
    2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
    2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
    2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
    2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
    2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
    2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
    2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
    2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
    2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
    2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
    2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
    2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
    2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
    2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
    2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
    2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
    2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
    2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
    2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
    2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
    2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
    2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
    2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
    2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
    2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
    2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
    2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
    2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
    2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2023, 2023, 
    2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 
    2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 
    2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 
    2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 
    2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 
    2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 
    2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 
    2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 
    2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 
    2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 
    2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 
    2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 
    2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 
    2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 
    2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 
    2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 
    2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 
    2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 
    2023, 2023, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022
    )), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -514L), groups = structure(list(birdid = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), levels = c("2167-56864", "2227-85702", "2247-39955", "2247-80346", 
"2247-80347", "2247-80421", "2247-88960", "2257-26581", "2257-26604", 
"2287-75580"), class = "factor"), Year = c(2022, 2022, 2022, 
2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 
2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 
2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 
2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 
2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 
2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 
2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 
2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 
2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 
2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 
2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 
2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 
2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 
2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 
2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 
2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 
2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022), JulianDate = c(44, 45, 46, 47, 
48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 
64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 
80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 
96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 
109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 
122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 
135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 
148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 
161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 
174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 
187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 
200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 
213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 
226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 
239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 
252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 
265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 
278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290, 
291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 303, 
304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 
317, 318, 319, 320, 321, 322, 323, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 329, 
330, 331, 332, 333, 334, 335, 336, 337, 338, 339, 340, 341, 342, 
343, 344, 345, 346, 347, 348, 349, 350, 351, 352, 353, 354, 355, 
356, 357, 358, 359, 360, 361, 362, 363, 364, 365, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 
22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 
38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 
54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 
70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 
86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 
101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 
114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 
127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 
140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 
153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 
166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 
179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28), 
    .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
        10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
        21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
        32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 
        43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 
        54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 
        65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 
        76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 
        87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 
        98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 
        108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 
        117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 
        126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 
        135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 
        144L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 
        153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 
        162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 
        171L, 172L, 173L, 174L, 175L, 176L, 177L, 178L, 179L, 
        180L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 184L, 185L, 186L, 187L, 188L, 
        189L, 190L, 191L, 192L, 193L, 194L, 195L, 196L, 197L, 
        198L, 199L, 200L, 201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 205L, 206L, 
        207L, 208L, 209L, 210L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 
        216L, 217L, 218L, 219L, 220L, 221L, 222L, 223L, 224L, 
        225L, 226L, 227L, 228L, 229L, 230L, 231L, 232L, 233L, 
        234L, 235L, 236L, 237L, 238L, 239L, 240L, 241L, 242L, 
        243L, 244L, 245L, 246L, 247L, 248L, 249L, 250L, 251L, 
        252L, 253L, 254L, 255L, 256L, 257L, 258L, 259L, 260L, 
        261L, 262L, 263L, 264L, 265L, 266L, 267L, 268L, 269L, 
        270L, 271L, 272L, 273L, 274L, 275L, 276L, 277L, 278L, 
        279L, 280L, 281L, 282L, 283L, 284L, 285L, 286L, 287L, 
        288L, 289L, 290L, 291L, 292L, 293L, 294L, 295L, 296L, 
        297L, 298L, 299L, 300L, 301L, 302L, 303L, 304L, 305L, 
        306L, 307L, 308L, 309L, 310L, 311L, 312L, 313L, 314L, 
        315L, 316L, 317L, 318L, 319L, 320L, 321L, 322L, 323L, 
        324L, 325L, 326L, 327L, 328L, 329L, 330L, 331L, 332L, 
        333L, 334L, 335L, 336L, 337L, 338L, 339L, 340L, 341L, 
        342L, 343L, 344L, 345L, 346L, 347L, 348L, 349L, 350L, 
        351L, 352L, 353L, 354L, 355L, 356L, 357L, 358L, 359L, 
        360L, 361L, 362L, 363L, 364L, 365L, 366L, 367L, 368L, 
        369L, 370L, 371L, 372L, 373L, 374L, 375L, 376L, 377L, 
        378L, 379L, 380L, 381L, 382L, 383L, 384L, 385L, 386L, 
        387L, 388L, 389L, 390L, 391L, 392L, 393L, 394L, 395L, 
        396L, 397L, 398L, 399L, 400L, 401L, 402L, 403L, 404L, 
        405L, 406L, 407L, 408L, 409L, 410L, 411L, 412L, 413L, 
        414L, 415L, 416L, 417L, 418L, 419L, 420L, 421L, 422L, 
        423L, 424L, 425L, 426L, 427L, 428L, 429L, 430L, 431L, 
        432L, 433L, 434L, 435L, 436L, 437L, 438L, 439L, 440L, 
        441L, 442L, 443L, 444L, 445L, 446L, 447L, 448L, 449L, 
        450L, 451L, 452L, 453L, 454L, 455L, 456L, 457L, 458L, 
        459L, 460L, 461L, 462L, 463L, 464L, 465L, 466L, 467L, 
        468L, 469L, 470L, 471L, 472L, 473L, 474L, 475L, 476L, 
        477L, 478L, 479L, 480L, 481L, 482L, 483L, 484L, 485L, 
        486L, 487L, 488L, 489L, 490L, 491L, 492L, 493L, 494L, 
        495L, 496L, 497L, 498L, 499L, 500L, 501L, 502L, 503L, 
        504L, 505L, 506L, 507L, 508L, 509L, 510L, 511L, 512L, 
        513L, 514L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -514L), .drop = TRUE, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")))

Please let me know if you need more details! I'd be happy to provide them.

I'd love to have a smaller data set that illustrates the problem. 2 birds with about 6-8 rows each would be small enough to fit on one screen and be a lot clearer. There's nothing about the problem that matters that the data is daily or more frequent - a couple rows before July 31 and a couple rows after July 31 in 2 or 3 years would be plenty. I appreciate that you didn't give us 12 rows per day, but 12 rows in total would probably be great!

@GregorThomas That makes so much sense. I'll definetly make sure to do that in the future. Thank you for always being so understanding when I don't necessarily put the best reproducible dataset. I always appreciate your comments.

Here's a simple answer on a simplified data set.
birds = gps.all.test[c(1,2, 168:171, 505:506), ]
birds$timestamp[8] = birds$timestamp[8] + days(29)

library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
birds |>
  ungroup() |>
  mutate(
    result = Year - min(Year) + 1 + (month(timestamp) > 7),
    .by = c(birdid)
  )
# # A tibble: 8 × 5
#   birdid     timestamp           JulianDate  Year result
#   <fct>      <dttm>                   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 2167-56864 2022-02-13 18:32:35         44  2022      1
# 2 2167-56864 2022-02-14 13:32:07         45  2022      1
# 3 2167-56864 2022-07-30 12:41:34        211  2022      1
# 4 2167-56864 2022-07-31 16:41:26        212  2022      1
# 5 2167-56864 2022-08-01 22:41:18        213  2022      2
# 6 2167-56864 2022-08-02 05:41:20        214  2022      2
# 7 2167-56864 2023-07-02 11:40:35        183  2023      2
# 8 2167-56864 2023-08-01 11:41:23        184  2023      3


That's a perfect fix. Much simpler than what I had been doing...thanks again!
